# WSL on Windows Terminal Preview won't start

Tags: wsl2, windows-terminal

Since some update (I am on Windows Terminal Preview 1.11.2421.0), wsl does not start directly any more. I have several profiles created, one for Arch Linux, another for Ubuntu, and another for Powershell. If WSL is shutdown, I cannot start Arch or Ubuntu profiles. I have to start one of them first at the Powershell before I can enter the right profile.

What I get if I try to enter the profile before WSL is started is this:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

[process exited with code 4294967295]
```

on Ubuntu, and this

```
The network name cannot be found.

[process exited with code 4294967295]
```

on Arch.

However, if I run WSL at the Powershell (so, if the distribution is running on WSL), then I can start the profile without problem (same at Arch and at Ubuntu).

The profiles are configured as follows:

**Ubuntu**
Command line: `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu`
Starting directory: `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\janus`

**Arch**
Command line: `wsl.exe -d Arch -u janus`
Starting directory: `\\wsl$\Arch\home\janus`

Again: since I can enter those from the Powershell, I assume the problem is with Windows Terminal Preview profiles.

Any clues?

**EDIT** If I remove the starting directory, it works, however it would start at `/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we should work on troubleshooting your `\\wsl$\` problems as a separate topic, my recommended way to launch into the home directory with a WSL profile in Windows Terminal is to use:

```
wsl ~ -d Ubuntu
```

The `~` must be the first flag after the `wsl` command.

Next up, see if `\\wsl$\<distro>` is available in File Explorer.  It seems like there may be a problem with the shared drive.

Comment: The setting has two fields. One ```Command line``` and the other ```Starting directory```. If I put ```wsl ~ -d Arch``` on the ```Command line``` field, what should I put on ```Starting directory``` field?

Comment: Ok, I put "Use parent directory" on the "Starting directory" field, and the ```~``` on the command line, and it seems to work. However, I just got a windows update, and now I cannot reproduce the error from my original question, so do not know if this solves the problem, or I do not have the problem any more. In any case, thanks, I will keep it this way, which seems more direct (to tell wsl directly where I want to go, instead of telling that to the Windows Terminal).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, for the explanations, and for that great nickname :-)

Comment: (Recreating comment due to formatting issues) Cool - Could have been a temporary failure of the `\\wsl$` network, perhaps due to other networking issues, or perhaps it was after first boot and took a little longer for the pseudo-share/network-share to come up.  The `\\wsl$\<distro>` directory is only valid when the distro is running, so it could easily have been a timing issue.